# Any API to query the usage of Bing Map API license

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, virtual-earth

We are looking for a API to query usage of the Bing Map API license. Right now, based on reading on MSDN [View Bing Map Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx), we could view the usage at Bing Map license account web site, however we would like to embed this usage into our own software with some usage tracking enhancement, so we are looking for the API to query this usage data.

Based on current internet search and MSDN document, we didn't find a way.

Or is there such usage query API for google Map API? Based on search, I didn't find that either.

If anyone knows such usage query API, please let us know. It is really appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps?

Comment: @geocodezip, I guess I am trying to see if there is similar thing at Google Map API as well. If there is such support at Google Map API, we might switch to Google Map from Bing Map although our code for Bing Map is already written.

Comment: https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: thanks @geocodezip, I went there and saw a lot of Google API, unfortunately I am new for Google API world and could not figure out what API is for usage tracking of Google Map API usage. Could you kindly point me to the name of that particular usage tracking API? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for accessing Account usage information. This information can only be accessed through the Bing Maps account portal: http://bingmapsportal.com To be honest, there usually isn't a need to check this regularly if your web traffic is consistent. If your application is designed properly you should only generate one billable transaction per page view of the page that has your map. If you capture web metrics already, it should be fairly easy to use that information to determine the approximate usage against your Bing Maps account.